# Question about reversed lists in Python

Tags: python, list, equivalence

I am very new to python, as you will be able to tell.

If I have a list:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1]
```

This evaluates to true:

```
a == a[::-1]
```

...but this evaluates to false:

```
a == a.reverse()
```

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

because `.reverse()` reverses the list in-place and returns none:

```
>>> print a.reverse()
None
```

and `a == None` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 4):

`a.reverse()` has no return value, so the comparison is
a==None
which is false

you can check with:

```
>>> str(a.reversed())
'None'
```

even better:

```
>>> (id(a.reverse()), id(None))
```

you'll see the same addresses

Answer (score 3):

If you want a new copy of the list, use reversed() instead.

```
a == list(reversed(a))
```

Comment: years of Python and I didn't know reversed

Comment: excellent: a Google search reveals the same feature for sorted.